# Allegro 5 - Bullet dispose when gets to the border

Tags: c++, allegro5

Me and a classmate are making an Allegro 5 game, a Defender remake, but we have some problems with the bullets.
When the bullet impacts a borderline the game crashes completely.

```
void Player::render() {
    

    al_map_rgb(0, 0, 0);
    nave = al_load_bitmap("images/naveV2_xs.png");
    

    for (auto& bullet : bullets) {
        bullet->render();
    }

    al_draw_bitmap(nave, x, y, 0);
}

void Player::dispose() {
    for (auto& bullet : bullets) {
        delete bullet;
    }

    bullets.clear();

    al_destroy_event_queue(event_queue);
    al_destroy_bitmap(nave);
    
}
```

Comment: There's not enough information here to know the exact problem, but one thing that sticks out is that the player object shouldn't own the bullets, i.e., be responsible for deleting them. Realistically, the player should request that the level create a bullet when firing and either the bullet keeps track of its own lifetime, which the level uses to know when to delete it or the level keeps track of its position to know when to delete it when it goes off the edge.

Answer (score 1):

I can't be 100% sure what the problem is, because you only shared a fragment from your code, but I see a few general problems:

In normal use, an allegro event queue would be a global object (used for timers and keyboard input) that is used for the lifetime of the game. If the player event_queue is shared elsewhere in the game, then destroying it in the `Player::dispose()` method would potentially kill it while it's still in use by the rest of the game, which could lead to the crash you describe.

Also, destroying the `nave` bitmap in the `Player::dispose()` method could lead to a crash if you're not careful to make sure that the `Player::render()` method is no longer called afterwards. If you still call `Player::render()` after `Player::dispose()` then you'll see a crash.

I suspect that the player is disposed when reaching the edge of the screen, and then either of the above two problems is causing the crash.

Furthermore `al_load_bitmap` should be called in the initialization phase of your game, not in the rendering loop. The name of your function `Player::render()` suggests that it's called every frame of the game. This would mean that you allocate new bitmap memory for each frame, which would mean a memory leak.

As a general piece of advice, you should take a close look at the lifecycle of variables, when they are created, when they are initialized, and when they should be cleaned up. Cleaning up data while it's still in use will lead to a crash like you describe.